# .htaccess url routing subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver

I have read at least 100 posts about .htaccess and cant seem to get a grasp of it. Everything i tried resulted in the 404 error and I know it works because if I type a line of randomness it gives a different error. What I am trying to do is url routing, the same way you would with an index page, with a subdomain.

I have a file routing.php which takes the parts of the url that come after it and includes files based on that creating different pages.

EX: `mydomain.com/secure/routing/application` should route through routing giving it the variable application so `routing.php` can build the application. `mydomain.com/secure/routing/login` should route through routing giving it the variable login thus building a login page.

I have the `routing.php` all set up. The breakdown, route any url containing `mydomain.com/secure/routing/` to `mydomain.com/secure/routing.php` no matter what comes after routing.

My latest attempt:(placed in the /secure subdirectory)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . routing.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /secure/

#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^routing/? routing.php [L]
```

Comment: that is one that i had tried in my long quest. I just tried it again and i still get the 404 error.

Comment: @user860869 works fine when I create a `secure` subdirectory from my document root, create a `routing.php` file, and put the above in a blank htaccess file. The routing.php output says: `[REQUEST_URI] => /secure/routing/qweqweqwe/123213213/sdsfds` so I can see my request is being routed to routing.php. Are you sure it's not routing.php that's returning the 404?

Comment: see for yourself, http://aliahealthcare.com/secure/routing.php is my page, removing the .php at the end should still load the same page but it just loads 404

Comment: @user860869 and these rules are in an htaccess file in your `/secure/` directory, you have `AllowOverride All` in your server config and rules in htaccess files are actually being applied?

Comment: I came into that issue, how do i verify they are being applied. Like i said if i type a bunch of 1's in the .htaccess file and reload the page I get Internal Server Error. Also yes these rules are part of a empty .htaccess so the url looks like mydomain.com/secure/.htaccess

Comment: @user860869 There are different options that can be overridden in an htaccess file, `AllowOverride All` means the htaccess can do everything (that is allowed to be done in htaccess). You could try putting in a rule that will always work: `RewriteRule ^foo http://google.com`, means if you go to `http://aliahealthcare.com/secure/foo`, you'll get redirected to google. If not, then mod_rewrite isn't allowed to be used in htaccess.

Comment: as you will see, i get redirected to google with that... it is set up now and you can try it

Comment: @user860869 no idea why that rule isn't working. Does there happen to be an actual directory called `/secure/routing/`? if so, then this'll never work.

Comment: there is no such directory. Well thanks for the help. Ii greatly appreciate it. Ill up vote for the help