# .htaccess not routing properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My issue put simply...

this works:
`RewriteRule ^foo http://google.com`

but this does not:
`RewriteRule ^routing/? routing.php [L]`

there is no directory or file name with the name routing. Please see this question for details:
[.htaccess url routing subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698882/htaccess-url-routing-subdirectory)

Since asking that question my understanding of the .htaccess system has grown significantly. I now undertand it, and from what i see everything looks fine. Changing that one line will redirect to google when foo is used and just render a 404 error is routing is used. Also I am sure routing.php is there and working.

Any suggestions to why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know what, I bet it's because you have `Multiviews` turned on. Try:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

at the very top of your htaccess file.

Comment: That did it... what is -Multiviews?

Comment: i had gotten it to work before i saw your comment by making the word it was looking for, the foo or routing, different from the php file name it was routing to. I noticed that making the word it looks for foo and then routing to routing.php worked when the word was routing and it was routing to routing.php it didn't work but with that line of code you gave me it works all the time no matter what.

Comment: @user860869 It's part of [mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) and when turned on, apache tries to "guess" what resource a certain URL-path maps to. In the case with `routing` and `routing.php`, mod_negotiation would take over and automatically try to map `routing` to `routing.php` so the rewrite rule wouldn't get applied.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it without the question mark?
Looking over the docs, I don't think you should use a question mark at all:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html  Try a $ instead.

Comment: Yes i tried it without the ?. And he said if the google redirect works then i have that set.. let me check for sure.

Comment: something i noticed. If i do a redirect using a name that is a file (so routing when there is a routing.php) then it does not work. So `RewriteRule ^foo routing.php [L]` does not work.